BLE HID Gamepad on nRF52805: Not Recognized on iOS
I am working on a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) project using the nRF52840 Development Kit (DK), which has been reconfigured to simulate an nRF52805 chip. The firmware is based on Nordic Semiconductor's ble_app_hids_keyboard example, with modifications to implement a BLE HID Gamepad. I am using the S113 SoftDevice and have successfully tested the functionality with Android devices. The gamepad is recognized as a HID device, and it works as expected on Android, verified using the hardwareTester website.
However, when I connect the gamepad to an iPhone via BLE, the same hardwareTester website does not respond as it does on Android, indicating that the iPhone does not recognize the device as a gamepad. The BLE connection is established successfully, but it seems iOS does not interpret the HID report descriptor or the BLE HID service correctly. I suspect there might be compatibility issues with the HID descriptor or the GATT attributes for iOS-specific BLE HID requirements.
Before I reconfigured the project, I tried with the source example of course, and it didn't work either.
I would like to have some help.

Since you modified the example it could be quite hard to give you any hints. Could you maybe [edit] your question to add more debugging details or even your source code? Have you tried the unmodified example to see if it works?

Edited.
And yes, i tried first with the original source code example. Didn't work either
